# RegExpValidator does not validate a URL pattern correctly

Tags: regex, apache-flex

The URL http://www.ftd.de/rss2 is not valid when I check it against the below RegEx in this (unadventurous) `<mx:RegExValidator>` :

```
<mx:RegExpValidator id="validatorURL" required="true" enabled="true"
    source="{inputURL}" property="text" triggerEvent="focusOut"
    expression="{resourceManager.getString('resources','general.urlRegExp')}"
    flags="i" />
```

This RegExValidator with the below RegEx validates URLs correctly **as long as they don't end with a number**. Any other valid URL seems to be valid.

Why is that? Flex bug?

---

### RegEx

I use [this RegEx](https://gist.github.com/729294) by [Diego Perini](https://github.com/dperini), which gets the best results in [this comparison](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex).

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$
```

The RegEx itself works great with the above URL, it validates correctly in any non-flex validator i've tested so far:

- [QuickREx](http://bastian-bergerhoff.com/eclipse/features/web/QuickREx/toc.html)
- [RegExPal](http://regexpal.com/)
- [JRegExpTester](http://jregexptester.sourceforge.net/)
- [RegExTester](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regextester/files/RegExTester%20Binaries/3.2.0.0/)

I've checked the RegEx with two Flex-based validators, which both failed to validate **any** URL at all:

- http://gskinner.com/RegExr/
- http://ryanswanson.com/regexp/#start

---

We use Flex SDK 4.6.0.23201.

Comment: It seems that it chokes at the unicode escape sequence.

Comment: @nhahtdh Further digging revealed the same to me. So i removed all the Unicode characters from the ranges, but it still doesn't work. Taking a look at the pattern itself now.

Comment: I don't know, but removing the Unicode escape sequence works on RegExr `^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z0-9]+-?)*[a-z0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z0-9]+-?)*[a-z0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Comment: @nhahtdh Yes it does, unfortunately it does not with the `<mx:RegExpValidator>` above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nhahtdh's answer made me check this issue again. It didn't solve the problem, but it pointed me in the right direction. I'll use the RegExp from his answer, as the suggestion conversion from `\uhhhh` to `\x{hhhh}` is necessary as well.

### Edit: solution

The actual problem is that when passing a RegExp as String to a `RegExpValidator` it has to be **double escaped**. So the Pattern should look like this if it is loaded from a resources file:

```
general.urlRegExp=^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\\.254(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\\.168(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?$
```

Now this can be used directly in the `RegExpValidator`:

```
<mx:RegExpValidator expression="{resourceManager.getString('resources','general.urlRegExp')}" flags="gmi" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The sequence `\uhhhh` doesn't seem to be recognized in the 2 online Flex-based testers. This is either a bug in the implementation of Flex regular expression, or possibly a bug in the implementation of the tester, or possibly a mistake in the documentation.

Please check whether the original regex works in your program before using the regex below.

This is a work-around for testing the regex on the online testers: replace all `\uhhhh` with `\x{hhhh}`. I am not sure whether it still works in the actual code. This is not documented anywhere, and I just found this out from an answer by other user.

```
^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$
```

[**Demo on RegExr**](http://regexr.com/v1/?33u90) (I used the test data from the link in the question)

Answer (score 0):

You can use mx.utils.URLUtil class:

```
trace(URLUtil.isHttpURL( 'http://www.ftd.de/rss2')); //true
```

It is also helpful for extracting different parts of url.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I am looking for. `isHttpURL` only tells if the protocol is present at all.