# Hiragana unicode contains roman characters and numbers

Tags: regex, unicode, actionscript

I'm doing a checking on a string on what language characters it contains. But using [\u3040-\u309F], it detects any roman characters, numbers, and punctuations as a hiragana letter. Ignoring there will be overlap of Kanji and Chinese characters later on, the current result is not accurate. Which other uni-code I can use for a more accurate result?

```
RegExp(/[\u3040-\u309F]/).test($string) && langArray.push('hiragana')
```

Comment: I think certain range of CJK have the same problem also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13957151/regexpvalidator-does-not-validate-a-url-pattern-correctly You need to use `\x{hhhh}` instead of `\uhhhh` in Flex.

Comment: yup, this work. Can set it as answer so i can mark it as correct? thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helps. I close this question as duplicate of the other one, since the answer is simply the same.